# Sharing session instances in PHP

Tags: php, session

I want to use session in PHP. But its showing some problems in my scenario.

I want to share same session in 3 different PHP files.

```
./sessionTest/testing1.php
./testing2.php
./testing3.php
```

if i store some information in $_SESSION in `testing1.php`, i cant access the same information in other 2 files

what should i do to make these 3 files share the same session instance?
Is there any other(except cookie) to make this possible?

P.S. These 3 files are executed by different calls, cant include one file into another using include() or require() functions.

Added session_start() at the top but still doesnt share the same session.

Comment: make sure `session_start()` is being called at the very top of these files

Comment: @Shakti: Absolutely correct. You should add this as an *answer*.

Comment: I added session_start() at the top of each file.. but those files doesnt share common session. i doubt that different sessions are been created for those files.

Answer (score 4):

Like so :-)

```
//<-- testing1.php -->
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['value'] = "Text!";
?>


//<-- testing2.php -->
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['value']; //Text!

?>
```

Comment: its showing blank for me. Maybe its because of the different path for those 2 files which are `./sessionTest/testing1.php` and `./testing2.php`.

Comment: That wouldnt matter, the session is not bound to a path.

Comment: You can make a file with <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> and look for the session category. Maybe its disabled for some kind of reason

Answer (score 1):

See this tutorial about: [PHP Sessions](http://www.coursesweb.net/php-mysql/sessions)
Maybe it can help you to understand the working with sessions

Answer (score 0):

Get hold of iehttpheaders for MSIE or web developer toolbar/firebug for Firefox and check to see if a cookie is being dropped by your PHP code / presented. Also check the path and flags on the setcookie header.

Answer (score 0):

Are PHP errors disabled?  If so, you could have a problem in code and just not seeing it?  I've had this happen where I had some white-space in the output stream before starting the session, meaning that the session broke because the session header wasn't sent first.  Of course not having php errors displaying it wasn't obvious as to why the variables were null.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update as I was having some issues here. Using [session_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) can be helpful if the site has multiple sessions/cookies. Look in your browser preferences to see what cookies the browser is storing. I've found you have to flush these cookies a lot to see what is going on if you are using different sessions.

```
<?php
  session_name('mySession');
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['value'] = "Text!";
?>

<?php
  session_name('mySession');
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['value'];
?>
```